# Looping over a hashmap and calculate min and stop when no points left

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, min

I have a hashmap containing (point, value), I calculate the minimum value in the hashmap. Second, the retreived point  I uuse it to extract corresponding values from a matrix.
then I store xmmin, and the points retreived in an arraylist

My objective is to not consider a point if it already exists in the arraylist.
I have tried this but It stucks with the first min.

Here is what I've tried

```
       List<Integer> dataPoints = new ArrayList(); // Storing parsed elements including Xmin           
       HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> clusters = new HashMap<>();

       ArrayList<Integer> listt = new ArrayList<>();
       List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(); //list of points for each xmin
       while(E.size()!=dataPoints.size()) {
       int xMin = getKey(E,MinX(E));
       System.out.println("Xmin "+xMin);
       if (!existsX(dataPoints, xMin)) {

       dataPoints.add(xMin);

       //checking id X exists in data points if no  return  close elements
       for (int j = 0; j < S.getRow(xMin).length; j++) {
       if (S.getEntry(xMin, j) > beta) {

       l.add(j);
       dataPoints.add(j);          

                   }
               }
           }
```

Here is IfExists function

```
       for (int k = 0; k < dataPoints.size(); k++) {
           if (dataPoints.get(k) != xMin) {
               return false;
           }

       }
       return true;

   }

How can I achieve that
```

Comment: Since points are integers, why not just change the `ArrayList` to a `HashSet` (or `TreeSet` if the order is important), so all items are distinct and will only be added once and you don't need to check this yourself?

Comment: I agree, but the checking is necessary, so that if xmin exists in Points , it should move to consider the next minimum. the issue with my code is that it stucks with the first minimum found

Comment: Ah ok, good point; I've read past that comment in your code "_if no  return close elements_". Shouldn't your `ifExists` method at the bottom be `if(dataPoints.get(k) == xMin){ return true; }` instead, with a `return false;` at the bottom if it doesn't exist? Or better yet: remove the `ifExists`-method completely and use `if(!dataPoints.contains(xMin))`?

Comment: you r right, totally agree, first issue resolved. but I'm stuck with an infinite loop since it always considers the first minimum in E hashmap

Comment: Let me know if this helped solve your current issue, then I will make an answer to accept. :)

Comment: Yes that helped with the first issue. and still stuck with infinite loop now

Comment: It would be better to create a new question for that (and provide the initialization for `E`, since the infinite loop is most likely due to the `while(E.size() != dataPoints.size())`).

Comment: okaay I'll do that

Comment: Can you take a look at the question for the infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `existsX`-method contains this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < dataPoints.size(); k++) {
  if (dataPoints.get(k) != xMin) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Which will immediately return `false` at the first item that isn't the `xMin`, while you want to accomplish the opposite: return `true` as soon as `xMin` is found like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < dataPoints.size(); k++) {
  if (dataPoints.get(k) == xMin) {   // != has been changed to ==
    return true;                     // Return true as soon as we've found it
  }
}
return false;                        // Return false if it wasn't found
```

Better yet however, would be to rely more on builtins that do the work for you. In this case your:

```
if(!existsX(dataPoints,xMin))
```

Can be changed to:

```
if(!dataPoints.contains(xMin))
```

So you won't need to make your own `existsX`-method. [Here the JavaDocs for the `List#contains` builtin.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1):

Your `ifExists` should be

```
   for (int k = 0; k < dataPoints.size(); k++) {
       if (dataPoints.get(k) == xMin) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
```